# How should I replace this closet flange?

Tags: plumbing

I purchased my home from flippers who did a non-permitted bathroom renovation. As I am replacing toilets, the toilet flange for one of the bathrooms seems to be completely abysmal - looking for advice on how to fix this. The existing flange is a Nibco 5851 4x3. I bought a new flange today thinking I could easily cut off the old one at the lip and then chisel it to remove the old one as I have done several times with PVC. Looking for the best way to fix this. I should note, about 12" or so down, I can see where the existing flange is cemented into the pipe. Ideas I have to fix this:

- Put a 3x4 flange into this flange and cement it all together and call it a day. This would lead to the flange existing ~ 1/4" above the flooring.
- Same as number 1 but cut the lip off the existing flange so it sits more flush
- Cut out (via an inside pipe cutter) the existing flange, add coupler, install new flange

This is on the second floor. However, the area is not accessible for a repair from the downstairs. Looking for advice/help, thank you!

[image]

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? "Abysmal" isn't a useful description.

Answer (score 1):

The flange *should* stand proud of the finished floor (in fact, it should be attached *on top* of the finished floor. So your concern about it being "...1/4 above the flooring..." is a non issue. It should also be screwed down to the floor to minimize movement.

I don't see anything wrong with your actual flange other than the height (too low) and that it is not screwed down. If it were me, I would screw down the existing flange to the subfloor below (OSB subfloor is visible in your picture) and get a "riser/spacer" to raise the height. These are readily available at plumbing shops and, when installed according to the manufacturer's instructions, will rectify the height problem.

proper flange install height:

[image]
pic courtesy of [Oatey, toilet installation equipment manufacturer](https://www.oatey.com/faqs-blog-videos-case-studies/blog/five-best-practices-when-installing-toilet-flange#:%7E:text=A%20best%20practice%20is%20to,the%20bottom%20of%20the%20toilet.)

flange spacer example:

[image]

Pic also courtesy of Oatey

Comment: I cut a piece of the lip off of the existing flange basically at the subfloor level attempting to separate the existing glued in flange. There are also some chisel strike marks where I first tried to split the existing flange. Photos: https://imgur.com/a/zfuFS3H

Answer (score 0):

I would use the inside cutter and simply cut off the old flange, and replace with an Oatey Twist-N-Set flange, or similar.  Actually, I probably wouldn't bother with the inside cutter since I don't have one, but I do have an angle grinder.